# Set is not updating when using set.add() and the script act as if it was a continue

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

This is my full code that I am testing. It grabs a list of cards from Trello and goes through the actions list on each cards to find those that were moved in the last day. It then gathers stats from said cards.

However, when a member is not listed in the members set(), the script does a members.add() to add the name to the set(). When my script gets there it will execute the members.add() but instead of going to the next line it doesn't update members and it goes to the next item in the for loop.

I'm really stumped by this one and didn't manage to find anything close to that problem here and on google. I tried a simplified version, basically just two for loops without the complex if statement and it worked, but I didn't drawn any good conclusion from that test.

Thank you

```
from reporting import report_init, report, Tech
from trello import TrelloApi
import logging
from config import __config__
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


logging.basicConfig(filename=f"debug_{datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')}.log",
                    level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.info(f"{__name__} just started.")
studios_dic = __config__()
tr = TrelloApi(apikey=os.environ["TRELLO_API_KEY"],
               token=os.environ["TRELLO_API_TOKEN"])
arg_list = ["[DIGI]", "[Print]", "[IC]", "[CS]", "[Frame]", "[Cadre]", "[Canvas]", "[Canevas]", "[Plexi]"]
key_list = ["# Digitals", "# Prints", "# IC", "# CS", "# F", "# F", "# C", "# C", "# P"]

yesterday = (datetime.strptime(str(datetime.now())[:-7], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - timedelta(days=1)).isoformat()
current_list_cards = tr.lists.get_card_filter(filter="open", idList=os.environ["TRELLO_LIST_ID"])
cards_completed = set()
members = set()
members_stats = []
for card in current_list_cards:
    card_checklist = tr.cards.get_checklist(card_id_or_shortlink=card["id"])
    card_actions = tr.cards.get_action(card_id_or_shortlink=card["id"])
    for action in card_actions:
        if action["date"] > yesterday and action["type"] == "updateCard":
            print("Action could be logged if it marked order as completed")
            try:
                if (action["data"]["listAfter"]["name"] == "Commandes Faites" or action["data"]["listAfter"]["name"] == "Check") and action["data"]["listBefore"]["name"] == "Commandes en Retouche":
                    print("Action should be logged if members exists")
                    cards_completed.add(action["data"]["card"]["name"])
                    if action["memberCreator"]["fullName"] in members:
                        print("Member Exists")
                        for member in members_stats:
                            if member.name == action["memberCreator"]["fullName"]:
                                for check in card_checklist:
                                    log.debug(f"Adding items in checklist to {action['memberCreator']['fullname']}")
                                    for item in check["checkItems"]:
                                        log.debug(f"{item} - {item['name']}")
                                        for i, arg in enumerate(arg_list):
                                            if arg in item["name"]:
                                                member.stats[key_list[i]] += 1
                    else:
                        print("Creating Member")
                        members.add(action["memberCreator"]["fullname"])  # line that doesn't work
                        members_stats.append(Tech(action["memberCreator"]["fullname"]))
                        for check in card_checklist:
                            log.debug(f"Adding items in checklist to {action['memberCreator']['fullname']}")
                            for item in check["checkItems"]:
                                log.debug(f"{item} - {item['name']}")
                                for i, arg in enumerate(arg_list):
                                    if arg in item["name"]:
                                        member.stats[key_list[i]] += 1
            except KeyError as ke:
                log.exception(f"{ke}")
                continue
```

Comment: You can confirm that `Creating Member` is printed? If it is, it *is* adding to the set, and all the code under it *must* run (assuming the loops are entered). The most likely explanations are the `if (action["data"]["listAfter"]["name"] . . .` condition is never true, the loops in the `else` are never entered because the collections are empty, and/or you're misinterpreting results. Regardless though, I think we'd need more detail, and the code as a [mcve].

Comment: Also note that sets can only contain one of an element by definition. If the element already exists in the set, the `add` will succeed, but nothing will actually be added.

Comment: The print statement is printed in the console. That is the part that baffles me the most, because it confirms that the if was True. I'll try to make the code more minimal.

Comment: If it's printed, then the element *must* be added to the set (unless it already exists in the set). What behavior are you seeing that suggests otherwise?

Comment: The set is empty all through the loop even when multiple different instances trigger the set.add(). In my debugging my script stops just before closing and I inspected the set and the list it should fill and they are both empty.

Comment: Did you check the log? `action["memberCreator"]["fullname"]` could be raising a `KeyError`. That is the only explanation I can see.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Carcigenicate. It was a KeyError indeed. When I isolated the code for testing the Key wasn't camel case like it should have.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. There's always a reason, no matter how bizarre the behavior seems.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple KeyError. The key fullName was spelled fullname in some places. Closing this.